# Changing format of bibliography slide in Beamer

Tags: beamer

In a Beamer document I am including the bibliography at the end using

```
 \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{\color{gray}References}\justifying
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \printbibliography
 \end{frame}
```

The resulting slides are numbered with roman numerals (I,II, III...) in black.
I would like to modify the numbers to print them with the same font and color as the name of the frame (References) and using arabic numerals.
Also if the references in the last slide do not fill the page they are not vertically justified (if there is only one reference in the page it is printed centered vertically, not at the top). I can not modify this behaviour because I have not found any reference to this in the documentation of the package.

Answer (score 1):

This roman number is controlled by the beamer template `frametitle continuation`.  You can change it from a roman number to ordinary number by using

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\insertcontinuationcount}
```

(the default definition has `\insertcontinuationcountroman`)

and you can set the color by

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle continuation}{fg=gray}
```

to match the `\color{gray}` you have given in the frametitle.  However better would be to change the color for the `frametitle` just before the references via

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=gray}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\insertcontinuationcount}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \nocite{*}
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=gray}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Using the following commands, you get the desired results

1. `\AtBeginBibliography{\justifying}` to justify the text of the bibliography
2. `\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=gray}` to set the bibliography item to gray color
3. `\setbeamercolor{frametitle continuation}{fg=gray}` to set `frametitle continuation` to gray color

MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, t]{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\AtBeginBibliography{\justifying}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle continuation}{fg=gray}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    
    \frametitle{{\color{gray}References}}
    
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Lots of thanks, it worked

Comment: Hello Motasem, where may I find these commands (setbeamercolor, etc)? I could not find them in the Beamer class documentation. I would like to be able to control the appearence of the references pages, in my presentation I have footers and would like to remiove thhem in thhe references slides, I used \thispagestyle{empty} before printing the bibliography, with this in the first slide of my references the footer is removed but not in subsequent slides and I do not see how I may manipulate those slides. Again, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Forget Motasem, I solved it, my pagestyle=empty was inside of the frame, I put it out and it worked. Tks